# URL rewrite, getting error

Tags: url, url-rewriting, mod-rewrite

I am having this in a .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^videos/([0-9]+)/?$ vis_film.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

My page is
root/directory/directory/videos/vis_film.php?id=2

but i want it to be

root/directory/directory/videos/2/

And ive placed the .htaccess file inside videos/, is that right? and what have i done wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you’re already in `videos/`, you need to remove that path prefix from your pattern:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$ vis_film.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: I still get 500 server error.. on the whole videos/ directory.. i tried videos/2 and videos/vis_film.php?id=2 but i just get 500 internal server error

Comment: @Azzyh: Maybe you’re not allowed to use a .htaccess there. What does the error log say?

Comment: I dont know how to access the error log.. I will need to ask the admin of the server

Answer (score 0):

You need to put it in the 2nd directory (root/directory/**directory**/videos/)

Comment: I still get 500 server error.. on the whole videos/ directory.. i tried videos/2 and videos/vis_film.php?id=2 but i just get 500 internal server error